# Problema conexión con MS SQL SERVER 2019

Tags: sql, laravel, server, conexión

Que tal estan uds colegas!!

En esta oportunidad le escribo por un pequeño problema, asumo que es de configuración pero no he podido resolver.

He estado tratando que mi aplicación se conecte con *MS SQL SERVER 2019*, pero me muestra un mensaje:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.(SQL: select * from [Departamentos] where [codigo] != 0)

```
ML_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
ML_HOST=mi_servidor/SQLEXPRESS
ML_PORT=1433
ML_DATABASE=mi_bd
ML_USERNAME=
ML_PASSWORD=
```

Ahora mi archivo `config/database.php` tiene la siguiente configuración:
Mi archivo de variables de entorno es la siguiente:

```
'sqlsrv' => 
  [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mi_servidor\SQLEXPRESS'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mi_bd'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
  ],
```

Necesito saber si alguien puede apoyarme con este dilema.

> PD: Utilice prueba de conexión con *PHP puro*, y si realiza dicha conexión sin ningún problema, mediante el siguiente código:

```
$serverName = "mi_servidor\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mi_BD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br />". $conn .'<br />';
    $strQuery = 'select * from Lugares';
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $strQuery);

    if( $stmt === false ) {
      echo 'Paso 1 - ';
        die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
        echo 'Paso 2 - ';
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
      echo  $row[0] .' - ';
      echo  $row[1] .' - ';
      echo  $row[2] .' - ';
      echo  $row[3] .' - ';
      echo  $row[4] .' - ';
      echo  $row[5] .'<br />';
    } 
}else{
    echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: ¿Es un servidor local o remoto? ¿Has probado con SQL Server Management?

Comment: Es local, y si he probado y revisado las configuraciones del SQL Server Manager y SQL SERVER Configuration Manager. No se que mas hacer

Comment: En tu archivo .env tienes claves como `ML_DATABASE`, pero en config/database.php te refieres a claves como `DB_DATABASE`. Por que haces eso?

Comment: Oye. no lo habia notado. dejame corregirlo, esperando que sea eso.

Comment: Ya validaste que en el SQL se permitieran las conexiones remotas?

Comment: Gracias. Muy agradecido por el apoyo. pero el error que ocurria era por los ODBC drivers que estaba instalado en la Pc el cual trabajo tenia el ODBC driver 11, 13 y 17.

Comment: Realice una limpieza completa e instalar solo el Sql Server 2019 con el ODBC driver 17. Y listo.. ya funcionò

Comment: Podrías describir lo que hiciste para corregirlo y ponerlo como respuesta por si alguien más llega a tener el mismo problema.

Comment: Bueno, en realidad solo tuve que depurar y desinstalar las versiones anteriores de MS SQL SERVER que existían en la pc en que trabajo, con todas sus características, inclusive los driver ODBC. Cuando no quedó rastros, realice un instalación limpia del SQL Server 2019. Y listo me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Agregar en php.ini lo siguiente:

extension=php_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64.dll

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).